# Why do I get pymodbus ModbusIOException on 20% of attempts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymodbus

I am receiving pymodbus.exceptions.ModbusIOException on 20% of my attempts.

```
'[Input/Output] No Response received from the remote unit/Unable to decode response' fcode = 3
```

The code is called via a QTimer event and I have attempted changing this range from 30ms to 5000ms and recieve the same results.The other 80% of the time the code works like intended. Is this a python timing issue or something else?

```
def Start(self):
    self.Client = self.Create("COM1")

    self.MbTimer = QtCore.QTimer()
    self.MbTimer.timeout.connect(self.OnTimer)
    self.MbTimer.start(1000)

def Create(self,com):
    client = ModbusSerialClient(method='rtu', port=com, timeout=1,baudrate=19200)
    client.connect()
    return client

def OnTimer(self):
    value = self.Get(1)
    print(value)

def Get(self,address):
    try:
        rr = self.Client.read_holding_registers(address,1,unit=1)
    except Exception as e:
        return None

    if type(rr) == ModbusIOException:
        if(rr.fcode == 3):
            ##This line is reached ~20% of attempts
            return None
        else:
            raise Exception("not fcode 3:"+str(rr.fcode)+str(rr.message));
    elif(type(rr) == pdu.ExceptionResponse):
        return None
    else:
        value = float(rr.registers[0])
        return value
```

Comment: Create your client with additional  keyword arg `strict=False` on Windows .

Comment: This worked, thank you. Do I need to do this on my raspberry pi as well?

Comment: No it's a workaround for inter char timeout on Windows, not so recemonded for Linux but no harm in giving it a try if something is not working , basically that switch would turn off the strict compliance of timing for frames with respect to modbus rtu